# How to control update of images from server

Tags: c#, wpf, assets

I have encountered a problem with displaying an image upon switching a view model. I do not know how to post images, so I am kind of stuck with describing the phenomenon.
The source of the image is an address on a locally running asset management.
It looks like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:20404/AssetManagement_Service/1.0/vmsasset//12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc/vtz_thumbnails/pic_iphone_02.jpg

Binding is pretty straight forward:

```
<Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="100">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="thumbnailAssestBrush"  ImageSource="{Binding ThumbImg, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
```

When I first activate the view, the path is correct and available upon creation. However, I do not see the image until I move the mouse from the list object. Then the Images update.
I assume that there is an issue between loading and displaying the image.

Is there any way I can force the UI to update again? Or control when the view is updated? Thanks so much.

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless. It only has an effect in TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings. Besides that, it is unclear why this shouldn't work - assuming ThumbImg is a dependency property in your UserControl, which itself is bound to an appropriate view model property.

Comment: @Clemens yeah, it was a hopeless try to see if it would make a difference :)

Comment: @Clemens I think the source itself is somehow there when the control is created. I can see the correct address. As soon as I move the mouse in the parent list, without selecting anything. Just the mouse over is updatet. As soon as this happens, the images appear.

Comment: How about using an Image element instead of a Rectangle with an ImageBrush?

Comment: @Clemens Sweet Lord! It works.